# Setting font size dynamically in react text component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to set up following layout in my RN application

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyReJ.png)

The following code gets this up and running:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut l ->
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.largeParagraph}>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut l
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  largeParagraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

The requirement is that the first and the second text components should take up one line each. I have tried using a combination of `adjustsFontSizeToFit` and `numberOfLines={1}` to achieve this which works.

However, both text inputs must have the same font size in the end after all the adjustments which should be the minimum of the font size after `adjustsFontSizeToFit` was applied to both the components. I have looked through the RB documentation but to no avail.

What would the most React Native way to accomplish this?

Comment: style={getStyle(24)}
then your getStyle function looks like 


getStyle(fontSize){
 return {margin: 24,
    fontSize: fontSize,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',};
}